# Delphi Build Server: find out which projects are affected by commit

Tags: delphi, svn, version-control, build

I'm currently trying to improve the performance of our build machine. A standard build, queued after each commit (svn), takes about 40 minutes. If there's already a queued build when committing, we don't add another one. So each build has the changes of 1+ commits. Since the commit(s) probably didn't made changes to all of the projects, the build time could be reduced by only rebuilding affected projects.

I don't have an idea how to find out, which projects need to be build. Is there a way to **reliably** find out what's affected by the commit(s) triggering the build? I first thought about going through the .dpr-files and check for changes in referenced files, but not all files are listed there, since we also use the searchpath...

If there isn't, is there at least a way to find out whether a project is **sure to be not affected**? I honestly don't quite know how to approach the problem...

Comment: It sounds like one of the trickier issues woulf be determining whether a particular DCU needs recompiling as a result of changes to other units it depends upon, which of course is a recursive problem, and of course you'd need to replicate the recompile logic the compiler uses.  The utility here http://forum.exetools.com/showthread.php?t=5196 might help with that.  Might be a lot less trouble to invest an a faster build machine, though;=)

Comment: yeah, I'm "investigating" in all kind of directions to improve performance, e.g. like RAM disks... I'll have a try with your link, thx

Comment: @MartynA all links seem to be down, only possible download is via the forum, and this needs registration which is disabled...
On the other hand, I don't know if i want to invest so much time in "hacking" DCUs, so it's not that big of a problem

Answer (score 2):

Following isn't an "answer" to your problem, but may be an aid to further thought.

Leaving aside other sorts of resource a given project uses (e.g. .RC and .Inc files), without knowledge of which source files, including all its units, it uses, I don't see how you could prove the proposition "This project will not be affected." by a given commit.

On the other hand, presumably you can generate lists of projects and source files that were changed by the commit, so by occasionally recompiling all the projects, you could get a list of DCUs that were generated as a result.

Repeating the above process several times with different sets of changes to source files, you should be able to gather some statistical correlations between .Pas changes and resulting .DCUs that are recompiled, and between projects being recompiled and generated DCUs.

Analysis of those correlations might allow you to identify which projects have a greater than X% chance of needing to be recompiled when given .Pas files are changed.

I imagine you would end up with a number of heuristics the could identify which project(s) should be recompiled following a change in a given unit and some deterministic rules as well.  An obvious one which would would be that once a change to unit A is observed to provoke a recompilation of project Z, whenever A is subsequently changed, Z should be recompiled.  Of course, once a project has been flagged positively by a deterministic rule, there is no need to consider other source files changed in the commit.

Another thing is that you could side-step the issue of needing to analyse the .Pas files USES dependencies to determine which .Pas files a given project depends upon by doing a full build of a project and making a list of the .DCUs generated as a result.

Btw, as this problem seems to be all about lists and rules, it would be fun to program in Prolog (Amzi Prolog has a great logic engine wrapper for Delphi that I've used for similar things in the past).

Comment: funny, I was just talking with a colleague about storing all DCUs built for each project in a DB, so that I can associate commited files - I'll definitely give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You may try to parallel build process and also use RAM drive to speed up it.
At my work, we use Ant for build. It can run some target in parallel manner, it's improve compilation performance x4 and more times (depends on thread count).

If you can't speed up build process. I have two approach:

1. You may write application, which walk thru project files (.dpr) and parse each .pas file it used recursively. After this you can compare file list with commit log and decide to build this project or not. Repeat it for all projects.
2. Save dcc32.exe build log and use it on next build to find files from commit. If you found file, you must rebuild project. The one problem - new files not covered, but you can force build if some files add in last commit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't look for other possibilites of improving the speed here - I'm well aware this isn't the only way to achieve a better build performance, but this isn't really a topic for SO

Comment: well, on second thought maybe it would be ok for SO, but still, it's not the aim of my question

Comment: Ok. if you can't speed up build process. You may write application, which walk thru project files (.dpr) and parse each .pas file it used recursively. After this you can compare file list with commit log and decide to build this project or not. Repeat it for all projects.

Comment: Sadly, as mentioned in my question, going through the DPRs won't capture all used units, since we also rely on search path

Comment: You can read search path from global and local dcc32.cfg and walk thru this directories.

Comment: But then I get all units, without being able to associate them to their project(s)

Comment: No, you must first read your dpr file and parse 'uses' clause to determine used units, now you must find all this units in search paths (read from dcc32.cfg or other places). Read each unit and parse 'uses' clause and find all units.. etc. Now you will have list of used units. There is only one small problem - IFDEF in uses clause, but you may ignore it (or parse it).

Comment: oh ok, got you wrong, sorry.
yeah, that might be a way, though it's quite a big task

Comment: @AlekseyKharlanov:  At first, I thought it was necessary to parse the uses clauses, but if you delete all DCUs and then do a full build, the created DCUs tell you which source files the compiler thinks the project actually depends upon.